# Janus-Gateway WebRTC Resolution

Tags: webrtc, janus-gateway

I installed Janus-WebRTC gateway on ubuntu server and started created a multiuser chat and broadcast.
When is run this example [Janus example](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/echotest.html)
In my own server i always getting a bad resolution 640x480 whatever my uploading bandwidth.
I tried to change default values on janus.js but without results.

Another info that may help.
When i run janus and run the exemple i get this warning

> [WARN] Getting a lot of NACKs (slow uplink) for video, forcing a lower REMB: 65536

Are there a way to handle this to allow the best resolution?

Comment: if you experience NACK´s it usually means that your upstream is not fast enough so changing to a higher resolution would only worsen the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be specified in a media object that will be passed as an argument to `createOffer` function, for example to a resolution of 1280x720.

```
var media {var = video: "16-hires: 9"};

echotest.createOffer ({
    media: media,
        success: function (jsep) {
        echotest.send ({"message": body, "jsep" jsep});
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // An error has occurred ...
    }
});
```

For more detail see [this](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/JS.html).

Answer (score 0):

For videoroomtest.js 
add video parameter video: "hires/hires-16:9/hdres/fhdres/4kres" in createOffer object

```
sfutest.createOffer(
    {
        // Add data:true here if you want to publish datachannels as well
        media: { audioRecv: false, videoRecv: false, audioSend: useAudio, videoSend: true },
```

to

```
sfutest.createOffer(
    {
        // Add data:true here if you want to publish datachannels as well
        media: { audioRecv: false, videoRecv: false, audioSend: useAudio, videoSend: true, video:"hires" },
```